# Windows Routing from one ipv4 to another ipv4

Tags: windows, nat, ipv4

Im currently hosting game servers on a window VM and im wanting to add multiple ips to the windows VM which I have done successfully. Now to assign my game servers(on the windows VM) to the public ips I can bind them in the specific games configs.

We use ESXI 6.5 to host the VMs and a Edge router X. We use nat inside of the Edge Router to route public ips to private internal ips. This has to be done because you cannnot route from public to public - if that makes sense?

So what I need to do is once the traffic comes to the windows VM via private internal ip to route it to the public ip. How would I go about doing this for all ports?

What I currently have:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=25565 listenaddress=internalIP connectport=25565 connectaddress=publicIP This works however is only for one port which I need more
I currently have this working on a Centos VM using iptables.

So what Im asking is how can i forward all traffic from one ip to another ip in windows?

Thanks in advance! 
Joe

Comment: None of this post makes any sense. It could be a language thing, but you’ve mentioned multiple different things without explaining how they are related together and the description you do have doesn’t make sense. You mention a “windows box.” Then mention a “windows server” with multiple IPs, then proceed to mention an “ESXI” server. Then to confound things further, you throw in an “edge router” and a “NAT router.” I’m not sure if you understand the difference and purpose of private and public IPs and NAT. At this point I’m not even sure how many different devices we are talking about here.

Comment: @Appleoddity Sorry about that, I have fixed the issues should be a bit more straight forwards now

Comment: "This has to be done because you cannnot route from public to public - if that makes sense?" – no, it makes no sense at all. That's how nearly all routing on the internet works.

Comment: @gawity Because there is multiple public ips assigned to my WindowsVM I have to bind each game server to a public ip. However on the edge router it doesnt work if I create a destination route from my public ip to the game server the windows VM is hosting which is also using the public ip.

Comment: I think I understand now what you are trying to do. But what I don’t understand is why. It doesn’t sound like a problem that should exist. Your comment “you can’t route public IP to public IP” doesn’t make sense. Your ISP provides a block of public IPs, which you should be assigning directly to the Windows VM. There shouldn’t be any NAT involved. So, your statement of adding multiple IPs to the Windows VM successfully, doesn’t actually sound like we are talking about the same thing. The public IPs should literally be added to the TCP configuration on the Windows VM.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks for the reply. We have been assigned a /29 block of Ips which indeed we have assigned inside of windows. As a example we want to host minecraft which favors the port 25565 as its default. So we have multiple ips so we can run multiple minecraft servers off 25565. As we use ESXI and multiple VMs we use 1:1 nat for some of the ips. What im having the issue with is essentially portforwarding but instead of the destination being internal ip its actually external

Comment: Ok. So the information I just realized is that you are trying to share the same public IP address with multiple systems using different ports. If that is the case, why are you assigning public IPs internally at all? You should just be using NAT at the edge router and basically port forwarding a particular public IP:Port to a particular private IP:Port on the Windows VM. Just use multiple private IPs on the Windows VM.

Comment: @Appleoddity The Ips are being assigned on the windows VM because the game servers need to be bound to the public ip. Im not sure if i can do what im trying to do inside of windows on the router instead. Essentially its like this: 
public ip => internal ip |
internal ip=>public ip

Comment: Lets take this discussion in to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75568/discussion-on-question-windows-routing-from-one-ipv4-to-another-ipv4)

Comment: @Appleoddity Hi, Sorry It says I need 20 rep to talk.

Comment: You're good now. Just up voted a bunch of your stuff.

Comment: @Appleoddity Still not working :/ sorry Says: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75570/discussion-between-appleoddity-and-jcbjoe).